# Why is Id AutoGenerated anew on UPDATE with Relation using Symfony Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mariadb

Symfony 5.3
Doctrine bundle ^2.4 ORM ^2.9
MariaDB 10.6.4

This has been rather difficult to diagnose especially as I was dealing with some complicated layered code. If I was sure, I would have filed a bug with Doctrine, but I want to first make sure I'm not making some glaring mistake or such, in implementation.

I have painstakingly tried to reduce the code to a simplified working  example. On my test database tables, there are additional columns that are not referred to in the demo code.

```
// src/Entity/Record.php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RecordRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecordRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="Records")
 */
class Record {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\RecordStatus", mappedBy="record", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Id")
     */
    private ?RecordStatus $recordStatus = NULL;

    public function getRecordStatus(): ?RecordStatus {
        return $this->recordStatus;
    }

    public function setRecordStatus(RecordStatus $value): void {
        $value->setRecord($this);
        $this->recordStatus = $value;
    }
}

// src/Entity/RecordStatus.php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RecordStatusRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecordStatusRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="Record_Statuses")
 */
class RecordStatus {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Record", inversedBy="record")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="RecordId")
     */
    private Record $record;

    public function getRecord(): Record {
        return $this->record;
    }

    public function setRecord(Record $value): void {
        $this->record = $value;
    }
}

// src/Controller/DefaultController.php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Record;
use App\Entity\RecordStatus;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function home(): Response {
        $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $recordRepository = $doctrine->getRepository(Record::class);
        $recordStatus = new RecordStatus;
        $item = $recordRepository->find(1);
        $item->setRecordStatus($recordStatus);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(['id' => $item->getId()]);
    }
}
```

When this route ("/") is triggered, the record is updated and the old Id is displayed. But after the update, checking the database shows that the record now has a newly Auto-Generated Id, that comes after the last previous record in the table. Note that this is on UPDATE and not INSERT.

My current partial workaround is to load the currently mapped relation if one exists and update it instead of using new RecordStatus, but it should also be possible to use a new Related instance if required (especially if there was no Relation assigned on first insert).

Comment: And you are pretty sure that your posted code reflects your actual code?  I don't see anything that would trigger creating a new Record.  Having cascade="persist" on RecordStatus::record is a bit unusual.  Maybe make a new project with just these two entities just to confirm that the code you posted actually reproduces the problem.  It sure seems like you have something else going.

Comment: @Cerad, This code WAS copied from a freshly simplified project. Nothing else in it. Just to make sure, I retried the update and Id: 9 got updated to 31. Why do you say persist is unusual? On insert, I need to save the recordStatus.

Comment: I said it was unusual because using a cascade on RecordStatus::record means that persisting a recordStatus entity will also automatically persist the record entity.  Sort of backwards.  Usually cascade is defined in one direction only.  But I don't think it is causing this behavior.  If you check your simplified project into a repo then I'll be glad to take a look.  Just guessing but some sort of listener or something might be clearing the record id.

Comment: @Cerad, See if you can access this: https://github.com/dVVIIb/SY_TEST. Also, I was specifying cascade for @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\RecordStatus", and not record, or am I confused on proper usage?